# Latest date from duplicate numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the table there are mulitple duplicate numbers with possible different dates.

For example:

```
TelNumber |   xDate     |
----------|------------ |
43422     | 2012-12-25  |
43422     | 2015-02-20  |
43422     | 2013-10-22  |
43111     | 2014-03-25  |
```

How to get the latest date from each number? For example, I want the result to be:

```
TelNumber |   xDate     |
----------|------------ |
43422     | 2015-02-20  |
43111     | 2014-03-25  |
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical group by situation.

```
select TelNumber, max(xDate)
from table
group by TelNumber
```

Comment: +1 for the simplest and perfect answer. Till the time "I'll be back" is back and accepts your answer.. take some points :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TelNumber, MAX(xDate) FROM table GROUP BY TelNumber
```